Computer crashed during Tortoise SVN repository checkout
I was in the process of getting all of the project files for work that I had just started and in the middle of the download my computer had crashed. I have some of the files, but I still need to get the rest of the repository. I tried to right click on the head folder to update to get the rest, but it keeps telling me I need to clean up the folders. I have some folders with red a exclamation mark. I tried running clean up, but that wasn't working. I only had "working copy status" and "Include Externals" checked. I don't want to click anything else because I'm concerned about messing something up.
What would I need to do to finish downloading the rest of the repository?

If all else fails, delete everything you have so far and start over. As long as you don't svn commit anything, you can't mess anything up.
